# Server Error 500 when uploading image

Tags: python, django, nginx

I am trying to solve a problem with uploading images.

I have set the error.log for Nginx to info.

First when I'm trying to upload, I get `413 Request Entity Too Large`. In error.log it says

> client intended to send too large body: 2524917 bytes, client:
>   my.client.public.ip, server: my.server.public.ip, request: "POST /admin/part/part/7/change/ HTTP/1.1", host: "my.domain.se",
>   referrer: "http://my.domain.se/admin/part/part/7/change/"

So I add this line in my config for Nginx `client_max_body_size 50M;` and restart Nginx.
When trying to upload again I get `Server Error (500)` with this line in error.log

> a client request body is buffered to a temporary file
>   /var/lib/nginx/body/0000000001, client: my.client.public.ip, server:
>   my.server.public.ip, request: "POST /admin/part/part/7/change/ HTTP/1.1",
>   host: "my.domain.se", referrer:
>   "http://my.domain.se/admin/part/part/7/change/"

Can't seem to find any answer when searching the internets.

Comment: 500 is from inside django application. So you have to check django logs

Answer (score 0):

How typical is it to figure out the answer after posting the question?

For others who might encounter this. Check the permissions for the folder where the files are being uploaded to.

I had only the user for Nginx set with permisisons to media folder.

Of course the user for my django project needs the permission to write as well.